# Related integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

According to the grading software, the answer to this problem is -34, but I was hoping someone could explain why?

[Here is the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ6le.jpg)

I get that the function is doubled because it is even, but I'm not sure what the next steps are.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Since $f$ is even, the second integral is 10 times the first plus $\int_{-3}^3 dx$.

Comment: Use properties of the integral (linearity).

Comment: Please type the problem in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-3}^35f(x)+1\,dx=5\int_{-3}^3f(x)\,dx+\int_{-3}^31\,dx=2\cdot5\int_{0}^3f(x)\,dx+6=-40+6=-34$$